# Eloquent 5 Query Builder with() prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a prepared statement speed problem when Eloquents Query builder is using the relationship `Model::with()` function.

I understand why I'm getting the error, prepared bindings cannot exceed ~65k.

Question:  Is it possible to use relationships `with()` and not have Eloquent prepare the statements.

It is taking a very long time to prepare the statement even if I chunked into pieces.

I understand it would be faster if I manually wrote the query and pulled the data, but it would be extremely useful if Eloquent had the capability to use `with('types')` and not have it prepare the statements.

Call

```
$customer = new Customer();
$data = $customer->with('types')->get();
```

Error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders'

Relationship

```
Class Customer extends Model {
    public function types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('apis\sinknet\dbmodels\Customer_Type','customer_type_entry','customer_id','type_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not paginate them? What do you want to achieve with this big amount of data?